# Hide rows across multiple sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I want to hide rows 16 & 17 across the following tabs in my workbook:

- Sheet6 (code name)
- Sheet7 (code name)
- Sheet8 (code name)

There has to be a better and more efficient way to write this code:

```
    Sub Macro1()
      Sheet6.Rows("16:17").Hidden = True
      Sheet7.Rows("16:17").Hidden = True
      Sheet8.Rows("16:17").Hidden = True
    End Sub
```

When this code runs, its take longer than I thought it would.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## I Adore ARRAYS - A Working Solution

### Hide

```
Sub HideRows()
  Dim arr As Variant
  Dim i As Integer
  arr = Array(Sheet6, Sheet7, Sheet8)
  For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
    arr(i).Rows("16:17").Hidden = True
  Next
End Sub
```

### Show All

```
Sub ShowRows()
  Dim arr As Variant
  Dim i As Integer
  arr = Array(Sheet6, Sheet7, Sheet8)
  For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
    arr(i).Rows.Hidden = False
  Next
End Sub
```

### Toggle

```
Sub ToggleRows()
  Dim arr As Variant
  Dim i As Integer
  arr = Array(Sheet6, Sheet7, Sheet8)
  For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
    arr(i).Rows("16:17").Hidden = Not arr(i).Rows("16:17").Hidden
  Next
End Sub
```

Thanks to:
[ProfoundlyOblivious](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9679683/profoundlyoblivious) for profoundly suggesting and providing the 'Toggle' version.
[GMalc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6388698/gmalc) for providing the idea of yet another way (not ever seen by me) of using an Array.

Comment: Looks good!  I'd consider replacing `arr(i).Rows.Hidden = True/False`  with `arr(i).Rows.Hidden = not arr(i).Rows.Hidden` and renaming the sub "ToggleRows"... but that's just me.  +1

Comment: @ProfoundlyOblivious: Thanks, nice going. The 'toggle' idea was the cherry on top. Now it's a real beauty.

Comment: Still think this is a great answer. Wish I could give you another +1.  Like you, Gmalc showed me something new here, but I differ from you because I think the real cherry on top is how you solved the error that still remains in Gmalc's post.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways; one that comes to mind is adding them to a dictionary and using `For Each` to loop through it.

Answer (score 1):

Use an array of worksheets...

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In Worksheets(Array("Sheet6", "Sheet7", "Sheet8"))
        ws.Rows("16:17").Hidden = True
    Next
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong here, but I don't think this will work.  OP is using codenames and they can't be referenced in this manner.  You'd have to loop through each worksheet in the workbook to test if the codename matched a value in your array of strings and only hide the rows if a match is found.

Comment: @ProfoundlyOblivious, What the OP was asking was there "a better and more efficient way", which this is.

Comment: @Hery0502, As ProfoundlyOblivious stated there are multiple ways to accomplish this, but I like Arrays.

Comment: @ GMalc I'm happy to eat my hat if I'm mistaken but I'm reasonably confident your solution will not work with codenames which were specifically stated.  But I don't disagree, it is an alternative and arraye are great.

Comment: @ProfoundlyOblivious: Nicely spotted.